# lapply - The difference between passing and not passing arguments when named argument exists in the environment

Tags: r

See the edit at the end for a reproducible example.

**Problem description**

When I run `boot::censboot(data, statistic, parallel = "multicore", ncpus = 2, var = whatEver)`, where I've defined `statistic <- function(data, var)`, I get error messages of type `FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (var = whatEver)`. The issue is that `statistic` is not able to see the value of `var`.

This does not happen when I call `boot::censboot(data, statistic, parallel = "no")`.

By debugging I can see that:

- If `parallel = "no"`, `boot::censboot` is running something like this:

  ```
  stat <- function(r, s){r + s}

  main <- function(...)
  {
    fn <- {function(r) stat(r, ...)}
    lapply(1:2, fn)
  }

  main(s = 2)
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [[1]]
  [1] 3

  [[2]]
  [1] 4
  ```

  In this case `stat` is indeed able to see that `s = 1`, even though `fn` is only a function of `r` (and not `r` AND `...`).
- But if `parallel = "multicore", ncpus = 2`, then `boot::censboot` runs something like this (note that the only difference to the above code block is `...` in `lapply`):

  ```
  stat <- function(r, s){r + s}

  main <- function(...)
  {
     fn <- {function(r) stat(r, ...)}
     lapply(1:2, fn, ...)
  }

  main(s = 2)
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (s = 2)
  ```

  In this case `stat` is NOT able to see that `s = 1`. This is the root cause of error messages of type unused argument.

  (Ofcourse, in reality `boot::censboot` calls `parallel::mclapply` rather than `lapply` to parallelise, but the issue pertains to the use of `...`. My understanding is that `...` means the exact same thing in `lapply` as in `parallel::mclapply`, since I'm able to reproduce the error message from `boot::censboot` in the repexes above).

**Questions:**

1. Why does this happen? How is `stat` able to see that `s = 1` in the ordinary case, where `lapply` doesn't actually pass along arguments using `...`? And why is this not true anymore when `lapply` does use `...` in the parallel case?
2. I cannot change the internals of `main`, which represents code defined in `boot::censboot`. How can I change `stat` so that it works in both cases?

**Edit: added reproducible example**

As requested by a commenter below, here is an example that reproduces the error in the parallel case. If you set `parallel = "no", ncpus = 1` in `boot::censboot` the code works as you would expect.

```
library(boot)
library(survival)
data(aml, package = "boot") 

statMeanSurv <- function(data, var) {
  surv <- survfit(Surv(time, cens) ~ 1, data = data)
  mean(surv$surv) + var
}

res <- censboot(aml, statMeanSurv, R = 5,
                var = 1, parallel = "multicore", ncpus = 2)

res$t
```

Output:

```
> res <- censboot(aml, statMeanSurv, R = 5,
+                 var = 1, parallel = "multicore", ncpus = 2)
Warning message:
In parallel::mclapply(seq_len(R), fn, ..., mc.cores = ncpus) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
> 
> res$t
     [,1]                                                     
[1,] "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (var = 1)\n"
[2,] "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (var = 1)\n"
[3,] "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (var = 1)\n"
[4,] "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (var = 1)\n"
[5,] "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (var = 1)\n"
```

Comment: The `censboot` docs say that the first argument to `statistic` must be the data, and any other arguments are passed using the `...` argument.  You don't pass anything via `...`.  I don't know why it works for `parallel = "no"`.  You should post a minimal reproducible example if you want more help.

Comment: Indeed `s` is passed to `stat` via `...`, and you should be able to copy-paste the code blocks above to reproduce the reported output.

Comment: You get the error in the toy example because `fn` doesn't have a `...` argument.  Add one, and it works.  But the real question is about `censboot`, and we don't have a reproducible example of what you describe there.

Comment: That's absolutely correct, a small change in `fn` would've fixed this. But as I described, I cannot change `main`, which represents the calculations that take place in `boot::censboot`. I can only change `stat`, which represents `statistic` used in `boot::censboot`. I can post an example with actual data later, but really, I believe that the code above highlights the issue.

Comment: @user2554330 I've now added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rewrite of the original post, that gives a better explanation of what went wrong, and fixes a possible bug in the workaround.

That looks like a bug in `censboot`.  It doesn't handle the `...` parameter correctly.  (More explanation below.) The reason you don't get an error with `parallel = 'no'` is that the code follows a different path.

A workaround is to use "partial application" to create a 1-parameter statistic function, like this:

```r
library(boot)
library(survival)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'survival'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:boot':
#> 
#>     aml
data(aml, package = "boot") 

statMeanSurv <- function(data, var) {
  surv <- survfit(Surv(time, cens) ~ 1, data = data)
  mean(surv$surv) + var
}

statMeanSurv1 <- function(var) { 
  force(var)   # Fix the value of var
  function(mean) statMeanSurv(mean, var) 
}

res <- censboot(aml, statMeanSurv1(var = 1), R = 5,
                parallel = "multicore", ncpus = 2)

res$t
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 1.564580
#> [2,] 1.503473
#> [3,] 1.602111
#> [4,] 1.440942
#> [5,] 1.594482
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Internally, the problem in `censboot` is that it does something like my workaround, but then it *also* passes `...` to its equivalent of `statMeanSurv1`, and that's an error:  it can only accept 1 argument.

The line `force(var)` in `statMeanSurv1` isn't necessary in the example, but in more elaborate examples it might be. It guarantees that the newly created function uses the specified value.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen "partial application" before, so this is helpful.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please note the edit to the `statMeanSurv1` definition:  it can prevent really obscure errors in more complicated examples.

Comment: Great, thanks again. I'll send a bug report to the maintainer of `boot`, hopefully they'll follow up the issue that lead to this.

Comment: No need to send a bug report:  I already did.